# Selenium IDE - function checkDate (Current date and date in the future)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide, user-extensions.js

In my user extensions i used this code to check the date but it keeps getting errors: 
`Selenium.prototype.doCheckDate = function(){
    var dates = new Date();
    var day = dates.getDate();
    if (day < 10){
    day = '0' + day;
    }
    month = dates.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10){
    month = '0' + month;
    }
    var year = dates.getFullYear();
    var prettyDay = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
    this.browserbot.getUserWindow().checkDate(prettyDay);
}`

The error: [error] this.browserbot.getUserWindow(...).checkDate is not a function

Does anybody have an idea how i can check the current date or dates that are in the future? Our systems fills a datefield with a date that is one or two years from the current date.

Thanks for your time and effort in advance. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all your function does is gets the current date.  What is your ultimate goal?  Do you intend to compare a the system date to a date from the field and verify it's 1 or 2 years later?

Comment: I want Selenium to check the current date (the system date in this case) and check if that's OK